# как отправить POST запрос с FoxPro

Tags: php, html, visual-studio, internet-explorer

Вопрос банально соответствует заголовку: как отправить POST запрос и получить результат (TEXT/HTML или JSON) на PHP-обработчик с FoxPro. Заранее прошу извинить, возможно не так выбрал метку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос. Возможно не совсем так. Вот пример кода, если кому понадобится:

```
LOCAL oWinHttp, lcURL, lcGet
oWinHttp = Createobject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
lcURL='http://ваш_домен/обработчик.php?name=Vasya$age=32'
oWinHttp.Open("POST", sURL, .f.)
oWinHttp.Send()
lcGet = oWinHttp.ResponseText
```

обработчик можно написать и так:

```
<?php
    else echo "yes";
?>
```

в итоге переменная lcGet будет иметь значение "yes".
Вот и все. Надеюсь, кому то помог.